# How to get a particular line from git log --merges -n 1

Tags: bash, git, bitbucket

When I try doing `git log --merges -n 1` I see the below output

```
Merge: 12hjkda1222
Author: testuser
Date:   Tue Sep 1 22:38:42 2020 -0400

    test-1.1

    Merge in proj/repo from release/test-1.1 to master

    * commit 'aczlxhclzsjcfpod2369841':
      release
```

I just want the line which **Merge in proj/repo from release/test-1.1 to master**. Tried to use git log --oneline --format=%B -n 1 HEAD and git log --oneline --format=%B -n 1 HEAD | head -n 1 which doesn't output the results what I'm looking for. Is there a way that I can a particular line from the output

Comment: @Christoph I tried that option too, It does print  whole ```test-1.1

    Merge in proj/repo from release/test-1.1 to master

    * commit 'aczlxhclzsjcfpod2369841':
      release``` not  ```Merge in proj/repo from release/test-1.1 to master```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requires a three step process.

1. Find the specific commit you care about.  You can combine this with step 2 if `git log` is a usable method for finding the commit, but often the right way to find it is with a separate `git rev-list` command.
2. Use `git log` with the `--format` directive, very similar to the way you are doing (just omit the `--oneline` which sets its own separate format).  Use the `%B` format to get the message body, including the subject line, as you are doing.
3. Pick the desired line, e.g., with `sed` or `grep` for a regular expression.  That is, use the command from step 2 with a pipe into a second command that finds the line you like.

Since in this case, steps 1 and 2 can be combined easily, you can use, e.g.:

```
git log --merges -n 1 --format=%B | grep '^Merge '
```

or:

```
git log --merges -n 1 --format=%B | sed -n -e 3p
```

(note that the difference between these is that the `grep` command will find every line that matches the pattern, while the `sed` command simply prints the third line, regardless of which line, if any, starts with `Merge` ).